SpringBoot Specification and projection not working together
I'm working with SpringBoot 3.3.3 and trying to use specification and projection together, seems to be a bit tricky.
I have two classes:

Person (name, age, att1, att2 ..)
PersonProjectin (just name and age)

Specification class where name equals "john".
Specification as itself works.
But together with projection not.
When I am trying to use it in repository, it is not possible to call
List<**PersonProjection**> findAll(Specification<**Person**>, Class<**PersonProjection**> proj);

Sometimes I came across with findAllProjectionBy(Specification, class) but it also falls on expectation argument when I am trying to add specification.
Is it really working together? Or do I miss to add some dependenciy?
I found this - but it is not with specification ...
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/projections.html#projection.dynamic
And according to Spring JPA query using specification and projection should work in version 3.x but as far as I tried it it is not working.
PS: not attaching too many source code or exceptions (to reduce the text :)) but if is necessary I can add complete example.
Mapping result is working (example bellow)
/* THIS IS WORKING */
public List<PersonProjection> getPersonsByName(@PathVariable String name) {
    Specification<Person> spec = new PersonSpecificaiton(name);

    return repository.findAll(spec).stream()
      .map(person -> {
        return new PersonProjection() {
          public String getName() {
            return person.getName();
          }
        };
      }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}


/* THIS NOT */
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Person> {

   // cannot find the method (even when it is written as generic method 
   List<PersonProjection> findAll(Specification<Person> spec, Class<PersonProjection> type);

   // also not working, missing at least one argument
   <T> List<T> findAllProjectedBy(Specification<Person> spec, Class<T> type);
}


